# Count of unique accounts that make at least one payment on any given day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle

| payment_id | Status | payment_date | account_id | currency | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72b30af0-323e-4931-8fcc-2c08ad8d0b19 | completed | 01/10/2017 | 2291969088 | GBP | 10 |
| 1b5341c0-508c-450f-a139-bc898f112fed | completed | 12/11/2014 | 7851880663 | USD | 20.000 |

what I am looking for is to get a "Count of unique accounts that make at least one payment on any given day"

so far I have done this

```sql
select Count(DISTINCT "account_id") as count_accounts
from "payments " pay
WHERE "payment_date" = TO_DATE('01/10/2017','DD-MM-YYYY')
GROUP BY "account_id";
```

but I am getting null but I should be getting 1 as there is an account that made a payment on the given day. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Also is there a better way of writing this query?

P.S my date is stored as "10-05-20 17:00:00", how do I change it to simple "10-05-2017"?

Comment: What is the type of `payment_date`?

Comment: It's a date, which I added directly into table and not through query

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes What you've linked is for the Oracle OLAP product, which I'm not familiar with.  In standard Oracle RDBMS, a `DATE` does include a time component.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B

Comment: Since Oracle's `date` is a misleading name for `datetime`, you need to use equality predicate only if you're absolutely sure your column doesn't have a time component. What you generally need for single day is `date_col >= trunc(date_to_be_equal) and date_col < trunc(date_to_be_equal) + interval '1' day`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to use a `GROUP BY "account_id"` and you can filter on a date range:

```sql
SELECT Count(DISTINCT "account_id") as count_accounts
FROM   "payments " pay
WHERE  "payment_date" >= DATE '2017-10-01'
AND    "payment_date" <  DATE '2017-10-01' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

*(Note: by filtering on a range, Oracle is able to use an index on the `"payment_date"` column. If you `TRUNC("payment_date")` then Oracle will not use an index on the `"payment_date"` column; you would need a separate function-based index on `TRUNC("payment_date")`.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "payments " (payment_id, Status, "payment_date", "account_id", currency, amount) AS
SELECT '72b30af0-323e-4931-8fcc-2c08ad8d0b19', 'completed', DATE '2017-10-01', 2291969088, 'GBP', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1b5341c0-508c-450f-a139-bc898f112fed', 'completed', DATE '2014-11-12', 7851880663, 'USD', 20 FROM DUAL
```

*(Note: It is bad practice to use quoted identifiers as they are case sensitive and you need to use the quotes and the same case everywhere the identifier is used.)*

*(Note 2: It is really, really bad practice to put trailing spaces at the end of your identifiers as the spaces inside the quotes are part of the identifier and you will have to put exactly the same  number of spaces at the end of every identifier [and they are much harder to count that visible characters].)*

Which outputs:

> | COUNT_ACCOUNTS |
> | --- |
> | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=753be66558ab4b0a5e1cfa963af14384)*

Answer (score 0):

I stored `payment_date` values again using `insert values` command with the desired format `(DD/MM/YYYY)` initially it was stored as `(YY-MM-DD)`. Then I used the `trunc` command to get rid of the time stamp. Works fine for now I guess

```
select "account_id", Count(DISTINCT "account_id") as count_accounts
    from "payments " pay 
    WHERE TRUNC(payment_date) = TO_DATE('01/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') AND "Status" = 'completed'
    GROUP BY "account_id";
```

Comment: "Works fine for now I guess" No, it does not as it does not answer the question as you will get one row for each `account_id` and all the rows will have a count of 1.